# cakephp: want to create a controller without database model

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing a cakephp application, I dont need to use any database tables for my home page, but cake asking for a model and database table, How can I solve this issue ? ( using cakephp 1.3)

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply set $uses of your controller to false, like so

```
class MyController extends AppController {
   var $uses = false;
}
```

Or put your view inside app/views/pages/home.ctp

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure what version was being used but for me, on 1.3.6, `$uses` is an array.

```
class MyController extends AppController {
   var $uses = array();
}
```

Details can be seen here: [3.5.3.2 $components, $helpers and $uses](http://book.cakephp.org/view/959/Controller-Attributes)

Answer (score 7):

For anybody having the same problem in CakePHP 3.0+, this is what works for me:

```
class MyController extends AppController {
   public function initialize() {
       parent::initialize();
       $this->modelClass = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anybody having the same problem in 2.1+ (despite what [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3a%24uses) says), this is what works for me:

```
public $uses = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer from the CakePHP official documentation at https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html:

> If you do not wish to use a Model in your controller, set var $uses = array(). This will allow you to use a controller without a need for a corresponding Model file.